# Unnest deeply nested json data in R

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

I have a huge list of json files to convert into data frames using R. I do not know the structure of each and how deep each file is nested, nor if it is possible to display the entire file into one data frame. I wish to automate the process.

I have tried converting to a tibble, then unnest_wider() each element, which works fine. That is just one level in the hierarchy of the file. I do not know how to proceed further.
Is there a way to automate the conversion of json files into data frames in R without knowing their structures in advance?

```
t<-readRDS("my_file.rds")
if(class(t) == 'json'){
  res<-jsonlite::fromJSON(t)
  #discard any empty elements, convert to tibble
  res1<-res %>% 
    purrr::discard(is_empty) %>% 
   purrr::map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>%
   as_tibble()
  elements<-names(res1)
   temp<-res1
  for (i in elements){
    temp<-temp %>% unnest_wider(i, names_sep = '_')
  }
   res2<-temp

}
```

[image: this is a screenshot of a file I am testing]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried `simplifyDataFrame = TRUE` in `fromJSON()`?

Comment: Thank you @VitaminB16, I like what it does with my data. how do I then turn it to one data frame? The current one I am working one has 203 elements in the list, 10 that are data frames of different row sizes and the rest vectors (int, Chr, num).